# What explicit permission am I missing that is preventing the effective INSERT permission at the table level?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a user that cannot update stored procedures because he gets an error that an INSERT cannot be done on one of our changelog tables. We checked his permissions to insert on that table and he has it, so we were confused as to why he couldn't insert. When we dug deep into this, it looks like we gave him the *explicit* permission to insert into the table, but for some reason he does not list INSERT as an effective permission. Our layout is server -> database -> table (pretty simple setup).

Note - for some reason when writing this question, it kept interpreting my inserted pictures as code and wouldn't let me post with embedded pics, so I had to use links instead.

**Explicit** server permissions:

1. ALTER ANY DATABASE
2. CONNECT SQL
3. CREATE ANY DATABASE

**Effective** server permissions:

1. ALTER ANY DATABASE
2. CONNECT SQL
3. CREATE ANY DATABASE
4. VIEW ANY DATABASE
5. VIEW ANY DEFINITION

**Explicit** database permissions:

1. ALTER
2. CONNECT
3. CREATE TABLE
4. DELETE
5. INSERT
6. SELECT
7. SHOW PLAN
8. UPDATE
9. VIEW DEFINITION

**Effective** database permissions:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOUvw.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Hwd.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrOEB.png]

**Explicit** table permissions:

1. ALTER
2. CONTROL
3. DELETE
4. INSERT
5. REFERENCES
6. SELECT
7. TAKE OWNERSHIP
8. UPDATE
9. VIEW CHANGE TRACKING
10. VIEW DEFINITION

**Effective** table permissions:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6fR2.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o62Kk.png]

Comment: So what is the error the user is getting? Don't forget `DENY` > `GRANT` so if the user is part of any AD groups/roles that have an explicit `DENY` permission is doesn't matter how many times you `GRANT` the permission to them, they won't be able to do it.

Comment: When trying to ALTER the SP, the error is: `Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure CustomTrigger_TableA, Line 22 [Batch Start Line 7]
The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'TableA', database 'DB', schema 'dbo'.`

Comment: Then, if they have been given explicity `GRANT INSERT` on the table, schema, or database, I would suggest, somewhere, there is a `DENY`.

Comment: The user is logging into SSMS with Windows credentials. If the user is part of an AD group/role that is preventing the INSERT, would the offending group/role be visible in SSMS or do I need to look elsewhere? We assumed that anything we would need to fix is solely contained within SSMS.

Comment: What is the definition of the DDL trigger `CustomTrigger_TableA` (that can't be its actual name)? Does it use `EXECUTE AS`? Is it inserting into a table in another database? Also, SSMS is just a UI that exposes data from SQL Server. Nothing is solely contained within SSMS.

Comment: This is the code for `CustomTrigger_TableA`: https://imgur.com/a/ykrAscq

Comment: `TableA` = `CW_DB_Changelog`

Comment: @AaronBertrand to your comment about SSMS being a UI - yes, sorry, I just meant that I hope this can all be resolved within SQL Server's domain and that I won't have to get with our head of IT support to look into AD group policies.

Comment: Don't post details that need to be in the question (the code) in the comments, and most certainly don't post the code as a picture. Put the code, as `text` in the question.

Comment: And what happens if you, as sysadmin, run this: `EXECUTE AS USER = 'Domain\TheirUsername';
GO
SELECT DISTINCT permission_name FROM fn_my_permissions(N'dbo.CW_DB_ChangeLog', N'OBJECT');
GO
REVERT;` (with a carriage return before and after each `GO`)

Comment: These are the results:

`ALTER`

`CONTROL`

`REFERENCES`

`SELECT`

`TAKE OWNERSHIP`

`VIEW CHANGE TRACKING`

`VIEW DEFINITION`

Comment: @AaronBertrand is there a way to see permissions granted/denied based on a role?

Comment: So `INSERT` definitely looks to be missing. For roles maybe see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36618/list-all-permissions-for-a-given-role

Comment: Looking at the server roles I am a part of, I see that I am only set up for the public role. For the database roles, I am a part of db_applicationdev, db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_executor, rpt_developer.

Comment: The rpt_developer role gives me INSERT privilege on the table. Not sure what else I could check. @AaronBertrand what do you think about this? We're hoping to avoid having to give the sysadmin server role just to be able to insert into this one table.